# How can I store and modify a JS variable from a md-switch in HTML?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So I have this md-switch made with AngularJS and HTML:

```
<md-switch class="md-primary" ng-model="vm.status">
  {{vm.status ? "Image." : "Text."}} 
</md-switch>
```

And I have a `vm.text = "Activated"` as the default value in the JS controller. But I dont know how to make it so that once the user clicks the switch, it changes the **vm.text** value to "Deactivated". In few words, its about changing JS code from the HTML.

Code of the controller:

```
angular
    .module('NewApp')
    .controller('MessageTemplateDialogController', MessageTemplateDialogController);

MessageTemplateDialogController.$inject = ['$scope', '$stateParams', '$uibModalInstance', 'MessageTemplate', 'JhiLanguageService'];

function MessageTemplateDialogController ($scope, $stateParams, $uibModalInstance, MessageTemplate, JhiLanguageService) {
    var vm = this;

    vm.isSaving = false;

    vm.text = 'Activated';

    vm.phoneTemplates = [];
    vm.phoneTemplate = vm.newTemplate('PHONE');
    loadAllPhoneTemplates(true);

    function loadAllPhoneTemplates(selectFirst) {
        MessageTemplate.findAll({type: 'PHONE'}, function(response) {
            vm.phoneTemplates = response;
            vm.phoneTotalItems = response.length;
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: `vm.text = "Activated"` and `vm.text.activated` are not the same thing.

Comment: Nope. vm.text = "Activated" is a variable inside of a JS Controller. And vm.text.activated inside the ng-model its just what I am using to show text in the screen.

Comment: I agree, but in this case `vm` represent the same variable, so you are checking for an attribute `.activated` on the string `"Activated"`

Comment: We'd be able to provide better advice if you gave the full code for the component

Comment: Oh, ok. Will update with different names.

Comment: The component is just what I initially posted, but I added some code of the JS controller for better clarity.

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to use the `ng-change` directive:

```
<md-switch class="md-primary" ng-model="vm.status" ng-change="vm.onStatusChange()">
  {{vm.status ? "Image." : "Text."}} 
</md-switch>
```

In the controller:

```
vm.text = 'Activated';

vm.onStatusChange= function () {
    vm.text = vm.status ? 'Deactivated' : 'Activated';
}
```

For more information, see

- [AngularJS ng-change Directive API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange)